# What is an initial state of a qubit in PennyLane?

Tags: quantum-state, pennylane, programming

I just started trying to use the PennyLane Python package. It seems like the `default.qubit` device initializes each wire as an up-spin qubit. However, I am not certain and could not find information about this online.

The documentation for PennyLane is a little bit unclear about the particulars (e.g. what state a default qubit is). Any suggestions of where to look to find information like this (or perhaps I am just missing it on the PennyLane site) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The default qubit state depends on the hardware, but PennyLane is an SDK. https://ionq.com/docs/using-native-gates-with-pennylane